# Angular directive callback resolve with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering how I could best solve this issue. In the code below I have a directive which has a callback function. In this directive same changes will be done to a variable passed in, and when the button in the directive is called, I want to trigger the callback. In the callback function in the controller I will do an HTTP POST to store something in the database.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  $scope.ctrlCallback = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve();
    }, 1500);

    return deferred.promise;
  }
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      callback: '&'
    },
    template: '<div><button ng-click="save()">save</button></div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.save = function() {
        var promise = scope.callback();

        if(!promise) {
          return
        }

        promise.then(function(result){
          alert('success, keep/do the changes');
        },
        function(error) {
          alert('not successful, undo the changes');
        })
      }
    }
  };
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <my-directive callback="ctrlCallback()"></my-directive>
</body>
```

At the moment I return a promise from the parent controller so that I can catch the result in the directive. It is also possible to return void, which will then assume that everything went fine. I however have the feeling that this could be solved a bit nicer. Is there anyone who has dealt with something like this before?

http://plnkr.co/edit/VdyFm4YRHQt7w2jMVnj6?p=preview

Comment: I don't think you need the if(!promise) return; Your ctrlCallback() will always return a promise. Both deferred.resolve() and return deferred.promise return a promise.

If you are worried about server side errors, you should build in a promise.reject() when that happens.

Comment: @Alex it is possible for someone to not return a promise at all from the callback function in the controller. This would then try to call .then() on undefined. It doesn't look like this in the code above, but the directive is part of its own separate module. But this is also not the issue I am having.

Comment: It is a bit of a weird solution, if only because I haven't seen other examples where a directive expects some non trivial return value from the bound expression. But it is a legit approach. (Btw, you don't need to do `$q.defer` - just do `return $timeout(...)` - `$timeout` already returns a promise)

Comment: @NewDev I've thought about it a bit, and perhaps it is cleaner to put the logic of error/success handling in the controller. So in the link function I would save the changes. But as soon as I get an error in the controller, I would rollback the variable (in the controller) which would then be bound to the directive. The nice thing about the current solution is, that the user will see the value update as soon as the promise gets resolved. And with the proposed solution, the value will get changed after saving and changed back when an error comes in.